# Delegate click View click event to Activity

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments

This is an Android design pattern question. I want to delegate all the click event handling of a View to the Activity that contains the View. Here is the structure:

The root Activity contains a ListFragment, the ListFragment contains a customized WebView, I need to call a function

```
public void handleClick() {}
```

in the root Activity when the user clicks an link on the WebView body. I am not sure how I can get a reference to the root Activity in the WebView.

Here is what I think: In the ListFragment I can do

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).handleClick();
```

That means the customized WebView should have a reference to the Fragment.

However, I don't like the idea of holding a reference to the Fragment. First it is because the customized WebView is not necessarily be a child of a ListFragment. It makes no sense for it to hold a reference to the parent Fragment. The second thing is holding a reference to the Fragment make lead to memory leak (I am not sure on this).

So how can I call the method in the MainActivity from the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont code your custom webView as a inner class in MainActivity?
that way you gain access to handleClick in MainActivity.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Or add a custom HandleClickListener (with handleClick method) to the webViews contructor and
implement HandleClickListener in MainActivity